# searchkick search HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, has-and-belongs-to-many, searchkick

How can I use https://github.com/ankane/searchkick to search both `Users` and `Skills` and return users with skills searched for. Most relevant result should reflect how many of the `skills` the `User` has.

My Models look like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    searchkick
    has_many :user_skills
    has_many :skills, through: :user_skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
    searchkick
    has_many :user_skills
    has_many :users, through: :user_skills
end

class UserSkill < ApplicationRecord
    searchkick
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :skill
end
```

I have tried the following, but no result are returned:

```
@search = User.search "*", where: {
    skill_ids: {all: [1, 3]}
  }
```

Comment: @fbelanger I know for sure that it should return results. I found that https://github.com/ankane/searchkick was way to complex for my needs. So I have switched to https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack instead

Answer (score 0):

Just because no results are returned, doesn't mean it is not working.

Explain how this should return results in your question.

```
@search = User.search "*", where: { skill_ids: [1, 3] }
```

Search Kick Queries:
https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#queries